# Does elastic Search Cluster Set Up leads to deletion of existing indexes?

Tags: elasticsearch, deployment, cluster-computing

As of now my elastic search set up exists only on one machine.Now I want to set up elastic search cluster using two nodes.If I make my existing machine as master and data node new machine,then will my existing indexex and data get lost from my master/existing machine?

As per my finding/experiment it got lost,please update if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this [link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/does-elastic-search-cluster-set-up-leads-to-deletion-of-existing-indexes/88840/2) for the same.